# ListBoxFor within IEnumerable model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

My model -

```
...
public string[] _SelectedCountries { get; set; }
```

and my view -

```
@using System.Collections.Concurrent
@using Example.Models
@model IEnumerable<Example.Models.vw_SpecialQuestionDefinition>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "SpecialQuestionDefinition", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/SpecialQuestions/Index.js")

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">Host Country</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    @*@Html.ListBoxFor("countries", null, new { @class = "sqQuestions" })*@
                    @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model._SelectedCountries,
                        new MultiSelectList((List<SelectListItem>)ViewData["countries"], "Value", "Text"),
                        new { style = "display:block;", @class = "sqQuestions" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-5 col-md-12">
            <input type="submit" value="Configure" class="btn btn-default"/>
        </div>
    </div>

    <input type="hidden" name="specialQuestionsId" id="specialQuestionsId" value="-1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="answerTypesId" id="answerTypesId" value="-1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="hostCountrysId" id="hostCountrysId" value="-1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="nationalitysId" id="nationalitysId" value="-1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="scopeTypesId" id="scopeTypesId" value="-1" />
}

<h4>Special Question Definition</h4>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Question)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AnswerType)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LookupTable)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CountryName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.NationalityName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ScopeType)
        </th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Question)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AnswerType)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LookupTable)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CountryName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NationalityName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ScopeType)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>
```

and within my controller -

```
List<SelectListItem> listCountriesSelectListItems = new List<SelectListItem>();
listSpecialQuestionsSelectListItems.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "All", Value = "-1" });
foreach (Country co in db.Countries.OrderBy(c => c.CountryName))
{
    SelectListItem selectList = new SelectListItem()
    {
        Text = co.CountryName,
        Value = co.CountryId.ToString()
    };
    listCountriesSelectListItems.Add(selectList);
}
ViewBag.countries = listCountriesSelectListItems;
```

so when I run the application, I get this error for my `ListBoxFor` -

```
'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Example.Models.vw_SpecialQuestionDefinition>' does not contain a definition for '_SelectedCountries' and no extension method '_SelectedCountries' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Example.Models.vw_SpecialQuestionDefinition>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

And I believe I understand why I get that error. Because I am trying to treat the model within the view as a single object, when in actuality it's of type `IEnumerable<Example.Models.vw_SpecialQuestionDefinition>`.

How do I get to _`SelectedCountries` from my model then?

Also, I use an IEnumerable model to populate a table beneath the list box. This list box is outside of the table and has no reason to be inside of it.

EDIT - POSTED entire view.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Should the model be - `@model Example.Models.vw_SpecialQuestionDefinition`?

Comment: If you model in the view is `IEnumerable<vw_SpecialQuestionDefinition>` then you need a `for` loop to generate a list box for each `vw_SpecialQuestionDefinition` (or better still, use a custom `EditorTemplate` for `vw_SpecialQuestionDefinition`)

Comment: @Win - I have a table underneath this ListBox that loops through the items within the model, hence have to cast as IEnumerable.

Comment: ... @Win - beat me to it. It doesnt look like you need to enumerate your vm... and if you do, your `ListBox` should be in a loop.

Comment: @duckmike that doesnt make a lick of sense, I'm not going to lie. ;) if you post your entire view and your entire vm this can be answered pretty quickly.

Comment: @wahwahwah - Posted entire view

Comment: Your edited view does not make a lot of sense. Can you post the full model for `vw_SpecialQuestionDefinition`. And what is the form actually for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am trying to treat the model within the view as a single object,
>   when in actuality it's of type
>   IEnumerable.

Your assumption is correct.

> How do I get to _SelectedCountries from my model then?

You need a new model and add IEnumerable inside it.

```
public class SomeViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<vw_SpecialQuestionDefinition> 
        SpecialQuestionDefinitions { get; set; }

    public string[] _SelectedCountries { get; set; }
}
```

Then foreach will finally like this -

```
@foreach (var item in Model.SpecialQuestionDefinitions)
```

Comment: Then how do I access that model within the view? I am relatively new to MVC and thought you could only have one @model definition at the top.

Comment: You just need to accept top ViewModel *(SomeViewModel in my example)* as a parameter in Post Action method. Normally, **DefaultModelBinder** can map the posted value unless you have very complex model.

Comment: @duckmike You don't need `IEnumerable<vw_SpecialQuestionDefinition>` most likely -- just `IEnumerable<SpecialQuestionDefinition>`. This doesn't appear to be a circumstance where you need both `SomeViewModel.SpecialQuestionDefinitions._SelectedCountries` and `SomeViewModel._SelectedCountries`...